# Geometrical transformation of a polygon to a higher resolution image

Tags: matlab, polygon, transformation, spatial, roi

I'm trying to resize and reposition a ROI (region of interest) correctly from a low resolution image (256x256) to a higher resolution image (512x512). It should also be mentioned that the two images cover different field of view - the low and high resolution image have 330mm x 330mm and 180mm x 180mm FoV, respectively.

What I've got at my disposal are:

- Physical reference point (in mm) in the 256x256 and 512x512 image, which are refpoint_lowres=(-164.424,-194.462) and refpoint_highres=(-94.3052,-110.923). The reference points are located in the top left pixel (1,1) in their respective images.
- Pixel coordinates of the ROI in the 256x256 image (named pxX and pxY). These coordinates are positioned relative to the reference point of the lower resolution image, refpoint_lowres=(-164.424,-194.462).
- Pixel spacing for the 256x256 and 512x512 image, which are 0.7757 pixel/mm and 2.8444 pixel/mm respectively.

How can I rescale and reposition the ROI (the binary mask) to correct pixel location in the 512x512 image? Many thanks in advance!!

**Attempt**

```
% This gives correctly placed and scaled binary array in the 256x256 image 
mask_lowres = double(poly2mask(pxX, pxY, 256., 256.));
% Compute translational shift in pixel
mmShift = refpoint_lowres - refpoint_highres;
pxShift = abs(mmShift./pixspacing_highres)
% This produces a binary array that is only positioned correctly in the 
% 512x512 image, but it is not upscaled correctly...(?) 
mask_highres = double(poly2mask(pxX + pxShift(1), pxY + pxShift(2), 512., 
512.));
```

Comment: You need to scale also. `+pxShift` shifts the coordinates. Now multiply them by a scaling factor that accounts for the difference in pixel spacing.

Comment: I tried to multiply `pxX` and `pxY` with the scaling factor 1.2891/0.3516=3.4666, but then the matrix dimensions 512x512 is exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have coordinates `pxX`, and `pxY` in pixels with respect to the low-resolution image. You can transform these coordinates to real-world coordinates:

```
pxX_rw = pxX / 0.7757 - 164.424;
pxY_rw = pxY / 0.7757 - 194.462;
```

Next you can transform these coordinates to high-res coordinates:

```
pxX_hr = (pxX_rw - 94.3052) * 2.8444;
pxY_hr = (pxY_rw - 110.923) * 2.8444;
```

Since the original coordinates fit in the low-res image, but the high-res image is smaller (in physical coordinates) than the low-res one, it is possible that these new coordinates do not fit in the high-res image. If this is the case, cropping the polygon is a non-trivial exercise, it cannot be done by simply moving the vertices to be inside the field of view. MATLAB R2017b introduces the [`polyshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.html) object type, which you can [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.intersect.html):

```
bbox = polyshape([0 0 180 180] - 94.3052, [180 0 0 180] - 110.923);
poly = polyshape(pxX_rw, pxY_rw);
poly = intersect([poly bbox]);
pxX_rw = poly.Vertices(:,1);
pxY_rw = poly.Vertices(:,2);
```

If you have an earlier version of MATLAB, maybe the easiest solution is to make the field of view larger to draw the polygon, then crop the resulting image to the right size. But this does require some proper calculation to get it right.